# Dynamic Paging of GridView with FlipView in Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, flipview

Here's my situation:

I have an `ObservableCollection<Item>` with a dynamic lenght that I want do show in a GridView.

The GridView(s) should be paged inside a FlipView, displaying six items per page.

What would be the best approach? Do I split my ObservableCollection manually into sub-collections `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Item>>` or is there a more elegant solution to this?

This is what my XAML currently looks like:

```
<FlipView x:Name="DashboardFlipView">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is simple and it works, so feel free to do it that way.

Technically to make it more elegant, you could use a special GridView control (or write a behavior) that adds mandatory horizontal snap points for each 2x3 grid. And to get the complete FlipView feeling you could add the next/prev buttons manually that interact with the inner scrollviewer.